# Serverless execution of a perl script?

Tags: perl, google-cloud-platform, serverless

so I'm trying to put together a pretty simple serverless application to learn the architecture better. It's a pretty basic thing - user uploads 23andme data, perl script converts the txt file into into vcf, that's uploaded to cloud storage, google genomics takes it from there and gives it to bigquery for annotation. Automating this into a pipeline would be pretty easy with a persistent vm, but I was hoping someone on here would know something obvious I'd just missed

I've got a decent idea of how to automate *most* of this into an automatic pipeline, but the perl script seems to be a bit of a sticking point. Might be because perl is one of a handful of languages I don't even know the basic syntax of, but does anyone have any recommendations on how I could make this work, short of just rewriting the 23andme-vbf script in Python or scrapping the 'serverless' part of this idea, since automating all of this would be pretty trivial with a persistent vm but I was hoping it might be something obvious I'd just missed.

It seems like other people have asked similar questions here in the past, but as of yet, I've been unable to find any of them with any answers.

Comment: When you say serverless, do you mean your software runs in some kind of cloud where you don't manage anything about it, or do you mean it runs on a client computer?

Comment: I mean that it would be an effectively static web application that the user provides the raw data file to, at which point it would be processed entirely by (presumably Lambda or Cloud Functions) followed by Google Genomics, BigQuery, and the processed result would be returned to the client javascript application for display, all without an actual provisioned VM anywhere along the way.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50396562/perl-script-in-amazon-web-services-lambda-functions

Answer (score 1):

This will be nontrivial even if you do know the basic syntax of Perl. One way that [the Google Cloud supports Perl](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/your-favorite-languages-now-on-google-app-engine) is to run [a Mojolicious app inside a Perl Docker container](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-custom-runtimes-samples/tree/master/perl). On your end, you would need to wrap your Perl script in a [Mojolicious](http://mojolicio.us) application that would be deployed to the cloud.

Comment: Yeah, that definitely seems pretty nontrivial. Ended up just finding a friend who's had enough exposure to perl from grad school and having him help me translate the script into python. Around which point I found out there's apparently a straight transpiler out there somewhere, which I should have assumed from the start. 

Thanks so much for answering my question in any case.

Answer (score 1):

Perl is supported in Google App Engine as described by the [Google Cloud Blog](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/your-favorite-languages-now-on-google-app-engine)

There are examples around particularly for running Mojolicious applications such [this Github Repo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-custom-runtimes-samples/tree/master/perl) but I guess it depends largely on how you want to architect your solution.

Running your Perl application within a container may be the simplest approach.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to convert the perl code to javascript using [emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten) and run it with [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/).

There are some online tools that allow you to run perl through an interpreter created with emscripten, running javascript. You can try them out by pasting some perl code in the browser:

https://www.shlomifish.org/microperl-web-repl-v1/repl.html
https://gfx.github.io/perl.js/

This is probably not an easy task to accomplish if you have a large perl script, but could be a starting point.

Comment: Thank you - in part because I'd never really heard of Emscripten and that definitely looks interesting, in part because 'rewrite or transpile the perl script in/to a different, supported language' ultimately proved to be the right answer, or at least, the one I got working this afternoon.

Comment: emscripten doesn't look like a perl-to-javascript converter. It looks like it ported the perl interpreter into LLVM and then JavaScript. It's not translating the Perl code into JavaScript so much as executing the Perl code with a Perl interpreter written in JavaScript.

Comment: @mob, that's totally correct...not sure how I missed that. I'll update the answer.